# Join List of List of Dicts on Key

Tags: python, dictionary

My list is like this:

```
l = [
        [{'g':'A','t':[]}, {'g':'C','t':['eaa']}, {'g':'B','t':['qe']}],
        [{'g':'A','t':[]}, {'g':'K','t':['ac']}, {'g':'B','t':['qs']}],
        [{'g':'A','t':[]}, {'g':'C','t':['ar']}, {'g':'B','t':['qdw']}],
        [{'g':'B','t':['eeq']}, {'g':'C','t':['eaa']}, {'g':'B','t':['zaa']}]
    ]
```

By checking equal sequence from dictionary key `'g'`, I want to join the lists on key `'t'` for each dictionary in each sub-list:

```
l = [
        [{'g':'A','t':[]},{'g':'C','t':['eaa','ar']},{'g':'B','t':['qe','qdw']}],
        [{'g':'A','t':[]},{'g':'K','t':['ac']},{'g':'B','t':['qs']}],
        [{'g':'B','t':['eeq']},{'g':'C','t':['eaa']},{'g':'B','t':['zaa']}]
    ]
```

In each list, check key `'g'` - if equal values e.g. `('A' 'C' 'B' and 'A' 'C' 'B')` then join on the value of `'t'`.

My code is like this

```
for i,j in l:
   count = 0
   if len(i) == len(j):
      for k in range(len(i)):
         if i[k]['g'] == j[k]['g']
            count += 1
            if count == len(i):
               i[k]['t'].append(j[k]['t'])
               del(j)
   else:
      continue
```

then error message was `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: Did you try anything? It's not 100% clear what you're asking. Some code might give us a better idea.

Comment: If you have tried something can you provide that in the question.

Comment: So, what is stopping you to do it?

Comment: sorry cuz i'm not good at english, i coundn't explain well.

Comment: thank you for reply and sorry for confusion making explanation : (

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
skip = set([])
for i in range(len(l)):
    cur = l[i]
    if i not in skip:
        for j in range(i+1, len(l)):
            new, flag = l[j], True
            for k in range(len(cur)):
                if cur[k]['g'] != new[k]['g']:
                    flag = False
                    break
            if flag:
                skip.add(j)
                for k in range(len(cur)):
                    cur[k]['t'] += new[k]['t']
for i in sorted(list(skip), reverse = True):
    l.pop(i)
```

Values from a list, dictionary or other such collections cannot be deleted the same time while iterating over them. That's why your code is giving an error.

Comment: Well, my solution is a little bit creepy, you can improve yours by storing the  indices to be deleted and later removing them.